# imploded data back to single words

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, insert

I have this data i imploded.

```
$fruit = implode(", ",$_POST["fruit"]);
```

I stored this data in a mysql table. The tablerow looks something like this:

```
ID: 1
UserID: 5
chosen: Apple, Banana, Orange
```

i realised it pretty stupid to store the data like this and rather want my data stored this way:

```
ID: 1
UserID: 5
Fruit: Apple

ID: 2
UserID: 5
Fruit: Banana


ID: 3
UserID: 5
Fruit: Orange
```

The problem is i have like 100 of theese records stored this way and wanna hear if there is a way with PHP to while loop out the old data and INSERT it back into a new table to make it look like the above example so i dont have to change all the records manualy?

Comment: The opposite of `implode()` is `explode()`. Use that.

Comment: Read each row from the table, use `explode()` to split the words, insert the new records in a loop, then delete the original record.

Comment: Is the number of `chosen` products always the same, meaning 3?

Comment: No it can be as much as 10.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick (where `$mysqli` is your connection):

```
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table1`")){ // select all data from the current table (where the imploded data is)
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `table2` SET `UserID`=?, `Fruit`=?")){ // prepare insertion in the new table (I'm assuming that the ID column is autoincremented)
        while($data = $result->fetch_array()){ // get data as an array
            $fruits = explode(', ', $data['chosen']); // explode the fruits
            foreach($fruits as $fruit){ // loop through the fruits
                $stmt->bind_param('is', $data['UserID'], $fruit); // bind data
                $stmt->execute(); // insert row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't actually test it, but you can try it out.

Comment: @Hazelcraft up to this day I'm still wondering if it worked or what, haha. I hope you were able to solve this by now!